# Error while creating trigger for add new row into table A after insert in table B in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Before read the question, please check this

[image]

I want to create trigger which insert new row into table A after insert in table B.
The value for attribute z (FK) on A is z (PK) on table B (so I pass new.z as the value for z on A), and for y on A, the value is y on C.
So, i think the trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_to_A
AFTER INSERT on B
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    select *
        from new, B, C
        where new.z = B.z and B.t = C.t
    INSERT INTO A (x, y, z) VALUES ('1', C.y, B.z);
END
```

But i found it's wrong and error. here are the errors:

> Error(1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

> Error(4,6): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

> Error(5,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;   The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

What do you think? and how do i fix it?

Comment: What is the error? Also recomend to write `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` instead of `CREATE TRIGGER` if you need to recreate/modify it.

Comment: @TaaviTiitsu Here it is: Error(1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, Error(4,6): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, Error(5,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

Comment: what's the version of the DB ? If `12c+`, then internal sequence structures might be preferred, rather than using seperate sequence unlike I stated within the trigger.

Comment: 11. The problem was solved (see the answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need such an `INSERT` statement along with a `SELECT` within the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_to_A
AFTER INSERT ON B
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO A 
    SELECT myseq.nextval, y, :NEW.z 
      FROM C
     WHERE t = :NEW.t;
END;
/
```

where

- `t`,`x` are presumed to be the primary key columns of the tables `C`
  and `A` respectively
- `commit` is not added just after the DML statement for the sake of
  transaction integrity for the applications through which the data into the
  table `B` is inserted